# Is there a way to show regular price on shop page in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am working on a website in fv.adburbs.com

In all pages other than single product page it shows only sale price.

Is it possible to also show regulare price strikethrough.

Glad to hear good news.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of WooCommerce, with the default TwentyTwenty theme, the regular price with linethough in the shop page is displayed correctly.

[image]

This function adds the regular price before the sale price in the cart page.

```php
/**
 * Display the regular price in the item price with a linethrough.
 *
 * @filter woocommerce_cart_item_price
 *
 * @param  string $price
 * @param  array  $cart_item
 * @param  string $cart_item_key
 * @return string
 */
function mytheme_wc_display_regular_price_in_cart_item( string $price, array $cart_item, string $cart_item_key ) :string
{
  if ( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->is_on_sale() ) {
    $regular_price = $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_regular_price();
    return '<del>' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</del> ' . $price;
  }
  return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'mytheme_wc_display_regular_price_in_cart_item', 99, 3 );
```

**IMPORTANT:** make sure you run at least Php 7.1. If you don't, remove the type hints and it should work fine.

Comment: I am not asking for cart but asking for shop page